# Android Studio cannot resolve dependency

Tags: android-studio

I use Android studio to create a blank project, but cannot compile.
below is its error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration':app:_debugUnitTestApkCopy'.
> Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
 Required by:
     project :app
  > Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
     > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'.
           > jcenter.bintray.com:443 failed to respond
```

I tried to use a proxy
and checked proxy settings with the failed url 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom'
and it show me success

but when I compile the project, it's still the same error.

this is my gradle.properties file:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=1080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=1080
```

this is project build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is app build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Do you really want to use jUnit for testing ? If not, you can remove that dependency.

Comment: no,but just want to make it working,ensure i can use other lib in jcenter

Comment: just check if you have disabled the offline mode or not.

Comment: do you mean the 'Offline work' setting of Gradle?Yes, it is unchecked

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle files here? both app level and project level

Comment: i update the file, thanks for you help @Prasheel

Answer (score 0):

finally, I solved my question

the proxy I use is a sockts5 proxy

the autogenerate gradle.properties file use a http proxy

after I change the gradle.properties it's worked

this is my new gradle.properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m -DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DsocksProxyPort=1080
```